# Add autoincrement to column and dealing with constraints [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add autoincrement (IDENTITY) property to the ID columns of some tables. I have done some researches that have shown that I need to actually drop the ID columns first and then add them again as IDENTITY columns. However when I try to drop an ID column I get a list of error message basically saying :

`-The object 'FK_OTHER_TABLE_MY_ID' is dependent on column 'MY_ID'. (foreign key constraint apparently)`

`-The object 'IDX_PK_MY_TABLE' is dependent on column 'my_ID' (Primary key constraint).`

So can I just drop the constraints (foreign key in other tables and primary keys in my table) and then add them again.

And if so, is there a method to do it for all the foreign keys in referencing my ID column that is less error prone than just dropping the constraints defined in the error message one by one.

Comment: Drop the two FKs first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sp_fkeys` to find all foreign keys based upon a table;

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

If you want a script then you can do something dynamic like this. There's a section in the middle where you'll want to put your script that alters the `IDENTITY` field;

```
DECLARE @PKTableName VARCHAR(100), 
        @PKName varchar(100),
        @FKName varchar(100),
        @sql varchar(max),
        @PKcolumnName varchar(30),
        @FKtable VARCHAR(100),
        @FKColumnName VARCHAR(100), 
        @parentColumnNumber int

SET @PKTableName = 'YourTableName'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FKAgainstTableList') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #FKAgainstTableList
CREATE TABLE #FKAgainstTableList (FKTable varchar(100), FKName varchar(100), FKColumnName varchar(100))

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PKDetails') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #PKDetails
CREATE TABLE #PKDetails (PKName varchar(100), PKColumnName varchar(100), Ordinal_Position int)

/* Let's gather details about our primary key */
INSERT INTO #PKDetails (PKName, PKColumnName, Ordinal_Position)
SELECT
     CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    ,COLUMN_NAME 
    ,ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1 
    AND table_name = @PKTableName

/* We need this when we're putting the FK's back on at the end */
SET @PKName = (SELECT DISTINCT PKName FROM #PKDetails)
SELECT @PKcolumnName = COALESCE(@PKcolumnName + ' ASC,', '') + PKColumnName FROM #PKDetails ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC

/* Let's grab the foreign keys and put them into a temp table */
INSERT INTO #FKAgainstTableList (FKTable, FKName, FKColumnName)
SELECT DISTINCT
     KC.TABLE_NAME 
    ,KC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + KCU.COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU
            JOIN sys.foreign_keys FK ON KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.name
            WHERE OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) = @PKTableName AND KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KC
WHERE STUFF((SELECT ',' + KCU.COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU
            JOIN sys.foreign_keys FK ON KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.name
            WHERE OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) = @PKTableName AND KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') IS NOT NULL

/* Disable constraint on FK Tables */
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR  FOR
    SELECT * FROM #FKAgainstTableList

    PRINT @sql

OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @FKtable,@FKName,@FKColumnName
WHILE   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql ='ALTER TABLE '+@FKtable+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+ @FKName
        PRINT @sql
        --EXEC(@sql)
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @FKtable,@FKName,@FKColumnName
    END
CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1


/* Let's drop that PK */
IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@PKTableName) AND name = @PKName)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+@PKTableName+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+ @PKName
    PRINT @sql
    --EXEC(@sql)

END

/* Put your script here to drop and create the IDENTITY field */


/* OK, let's apply that PK (clustered) */
SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+@PKTableName +' ADD  CONSTRAINT '+@PKName+' PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ('+@PKcolumnName+' ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]'
PRINT(@sql)
--EXEC(@sql)

/* Put the FK's back on */
DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR  FOR
    SELECT  * FROM #FKAgainstTableList
OPEN cursor2
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor2 INTO @FKtable,@FKName,@FKColumnName
WHILE   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+@FKtable+' WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT '+ @FKName+' FOREIGN KEY(['+REPLACE(@FKColumnName,',','],[')+'])
        REFERENCES ['+@PKTableName+'] (['+REPLACE(@PKcolumnName,' ASC,','],[')+'])'
        PRINT(@sql)
        --EXEC(@sql)

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor2 INTO @FKtable,@FKName,@FKColumnName
    END
CLOSE cursor2
DEALLOCATE cursor2


/* Tidy up */
DROP TABLE #FKAgainstTableList
DROP TABLE #PKDetails
```

Please note that I've taken this script for some work I had to do to convert a non-clustered PK into a clustered one and the original code has been taken from various sources and modified to suit my needs. I can't take credit for all of this code.

I've also commented out the execution of the code so that you can see what it's going to be doing in the messages tab of `SSMS`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I when I will have deleted all the foreign key constraints, How can I make sure I identically recreate them afterwards?

Comment: Take a look at #FKAgainstTableList, it puts all the information that you need into a temp table at the beginning of the script. It then uses this table  to get the details when recreating the FK's. If you run this you will see the commands it is going to run in the messages tab of SSMS. It won't execute as i've commented out the exec functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the referenced foreign keys first before doing what you need to do to make your identity column work.